# Multiple instance in one Django form for editing profile model objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-2.2

I used the profile method to be able to customize the user model. I also use [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html#sign-up-with-profile-model) site to ***create a registration 
form in which both the user and the profile can be created at the same time***.

**Now I want to write `edite_user` view.** In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647810/django-creating-form-for-editing-multiple-instance-of-model) I also find out that must use `modelformset_factory`
to create `edit_view`for this goal.

This is my files:

```
#models.py 
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    degree = models.CharField()

#forms 
class SignUpAdminForm(UserCreationForm):
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    degree = forms.CharField()
    #Also_their_is_another_fields_here
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'bio',
            'degree',
        )
#Views.py
def add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpAdminForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.profile.bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
            user.profile.bio = form.cleaned_data['degree']
            user.save()
            return redirect('view_user')
    else:
        form = SignUpAdminForm()
    template = 'add_user.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)

def edit_user(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        UserFormSet = modelformset_factory(user, form=SignUpAdminForm)
        if UserFormSet.is_valid():
            edit_user = UserFormSet.save(commit=False)
            edit_user.save()
            return redirect('view_user')
    else:
        UserFormSet = modelformset_factory(User, form=SignUpAdminForm)
    template = 'edit_user.html'
    context = {'UserFormSet': UserFormSet}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

But this view did not work.I Also see these links: [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644498/editing-related-models-in-profile-form-using-django-profiles),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828463/edit-profile-in-django) and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422846/django-multiple-models-one-form); but they couldn't help me and I didn't understand
what to do. ***Can you help me write the editing view?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to set initial user

how about this?

```
def edit_user(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        UserFormSet = SignUpAdminForm(request.POST, instance = user)
        if UserFormSet.is_valid():
            edit_user = UserFormSet.save(commit=False)
            edit_user.profile.bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
            edit_user.profile.degree = form.cleaned_data['degree']
            edit_user.save()
            return redirect('view_user')
    else:
        UserFormSet = SignUpAdminForm(instance = user,initial={
            'bio':profile.bio,
            'degree': profile.degree})
    template = 'edit_user.html'
    context = {'UserFormSet': UserFormSet}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: It raise this error: `TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable` @flakavir

Comment: oh sorry, change initial with instance
UserFormSet = SignUpAdminForm(instance = user)

Comment: I did work. But still exist one another problem for  `bio` and `degree` field of `Profile` model: it doesn't show previous value that I set when I created user. how can handel this? @flakavir

Comment: use initial value if you want...
UserFormSet = SignUpAdminForm(instance = user, initial={'bio': user.profile.bio, 'degree': user.profile.degree})